# Is there way to have to EF code first Entities with the same type name in the same assembly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm currently getting the following error with my EF code first context:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Offer'. Previously found CLR type 'CakeExtracter.CakeMarketingApi.Entities.Offer', newly found CLR type 'Cake
Extracter.Data.CakeTraffic.Offer'.
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection
, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel.CreateObjectContext[TContext](DbConnection existingConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
```

Is there any way to solve this other than creating a separate project so the two contexts live in different assemblies?

Comment: I believe i tracked down a workitem for EF6 about this - http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/911 - trying to determine if it describes my issue

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to install EF6 in which this issue is resolved.

I used the PMC command: `Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre`

Then I had to make an adjustment to my code because the `EntityState` enumeration moved into the `System.Data` namespace, then it worked perfectly.